# difference between __repr__() and just calling class instance

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my class

```
class abc:
    def __init__(self, l):
        self.l =l
    def __repr__(self):
        return '['+ '\n'.join([str(_) for _ in self.l]) + ']'
    def __str__(self):
        return 'ololo'
```

```
a = abc([1,2,3])
```

When I call `a.__repr__()` I get this in console

```
>a.__repr__()
 '[1\n2\n3]'
```

When I just call `a`, I got this

```
>a
[1
2
3]
```

Why there is difference between outputs? What methods are called, then I just type `a`?

PS.
When I call `print(a.__repr__())`, I get

```
>print(a.__repr__())
[1
2
3]
```

I thought that print just calls `__str__()` method of object, but

```
>a.__repr__().__str__()
'[1\n2\n3]'
```

Comment: The Python shell returns the "repr" of the expression you entered (if any). In first variant it is the representation of the representation string of the object. In the second it is only the representation string.

Comment: `print(a.__repr__())` and you'll have the same thing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy , yes, but when I type a.__repr__().__str__() I got again another thing! I thought that print() just calls the __str__ method

Comment: @Slavka, what's important is not that it *calls* it, but that it *prints it directly to stdout*, instead of taking the `repr()` of the result (received from the call you mention) and printing _that_, which is what the Python REPL usually does.

Comment: So, what you're doing is equivalent to `print(repr(a.__repr__()))`. See the link to the duplicate question up at the top.

Comment: So when you type `a.__repr__().__str__()` at the REPL, what happens is `print(repr(a.__repr__().__str__()))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

repr show you the string itself while the the instance is evaluating it to the console...

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are already elsewhere in the knowledge base. See the *Answer Well-Asked Questions* section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and particularly the bullet point regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before".

Comment: Will check it out, thanks and sorry...